# I want to remove randomly appearing 'A' 'B' 'C' strings from a list

Tags: python, string, list

I possess the following listing results. This is the result obtained from the AB test of the article.

```
texts = [
    'A text',
    '89',
    '71%',
    '10%',

    'B',
    'B text',
    '110',
    '50%',
    '9%',

    'C',
    'C text',
    '30%',
    '4%'
    ]

texts2 = [
    'A'
    'A text',
    '89',
    '71%',
    '10%',

    'B',
    'B text',
    '110',
    '50%',
    '9%',

    'C text',
    '30%',
    '4%'
    ]
```

Only the best result in this list does not contain any of the letters 'A', 'B', or 'C'. In this list, the A result does not contain 'A'.
But I am wondering what to do with the possibility of a list that appears without 'B' and 'C' as strings.

I was trying the following code now, but it does not work.

Is there a good solution?

```
while ('A' or 'B' or 'C') in texts:
    try:
        texts.remove('A')
        texts.remove('B')
        texts.remove('C')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Comment: why are you using a loop? if you try once to remove them and it doesn't work then executing the same instruction again and again will not improve the situation.

Comment: Python is not English, dude (but it's close). `('A' or 'B' or 'C')` evaluates to `'A'`. So you are checking for `while 'A' in texts:`. Try separate clauses for each check: `('A' in texts) or ('B' in texts)` etc

Comment: `('A' or 'B' or 'C') in texts` will not do what you intend. `'A' in texts or 'B' in texts or 'C' in texts` would get closer to what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
texts = [
    'A text',
    '89',
    '71%',
    '10%',

    'B',
    'B text',
    '110',
    '50%',
    '9%',

    'C',
    'C text',
    '30%',
    '4%'
    ]

exclude = {'A','B','C'}
t = [x for x in texts if (x not in exclude)]
print(t)
```

Output: `['A text', '89', '71%', '10%', 'B text', '110', '50%', '9%', 'C text', '30%', '4%']`